# Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must stat with '.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have converted some C# code to VB.net

C# code:

```
private static List<Hotels> LoadData()
{  
        List<Hotels> lst = new List<Hotels>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
        var bl = new BAL();  
        dt = bl.GetDataTable("tbl_Hotel");  
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)  
        {  
            lst.Add(new Hotels { Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PId"]), HotelName =     Convert.ToString(dr["HotelName"]) });

        } 
        return lst;  
    }
```

Code converted to VB:

```
Private Shared Function LoadData() As List(Of Makes)
    Dim bl As New BAL
    Dim lst As New List(Of Makes)()

    Dim dt As New DataTable()

    dt = bl.GetDataTable2()

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    lst.Add(New Makes() With { _

       'Here an error occur on "Key" Word

        Key .Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr("ID")), _
        Key .MakeName = Convert.ToString(dr("CHASSIS_NO")), _
        Key .Model = Convert.ToString(dr("MODEL")), _
        Key .Color = Convert.ToString(dr("color")), _

    })
    Next

    Return lst

End Function
```

Error which I am facing is

> Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.

I mostly use Asp.net C# and almost vb and C# can be understood but some point like this I am not getting the point why I am getting this error plz help as I am a newbie in vb.net

Comment: "I have converted some C# code to VB.net" - What a truly odd thing to do! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only use `Key` with anonymous types - not object initializers. So your VB code should be:

```
lst.Add(New Makes() With { _
    .Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr("ID")), _
    .MakeName = Convert.ToString(dr("CHASSIS_NO")), _
    .Model = Convert.ToString(dr("MODEL")), _
    .Color = Convert.ToString(dr("color")), _
})
```

On an anonymous type, [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531349.aspx) makes the property read-only and means it's part of the `Equals` / `GetHashCode` implementations. Neither of those differences is relevant in a named type.